# PreparedStatement not executing correctly

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

```
query = "SELECT * FROM POST_COMMENT WHERE Post_date_time= ? AND Post_User= !;";
     query = query.replace("?", "'"+post.getDatetime()+"'");
     query = query.replace("!", Integer.toString(post.getPublisher().getID()));

    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

The resulting query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM POST_COMMENT WHERE Post_date_time= '2013-04-12 07:20:34.0' AND Post_User= 378;
```

Which works right in the MySQL prompt line but, when launched from prepared statement throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:20:34.0 AND Post_User=378' at line 1
```

But

```
pstm.setString(1, post.getDatetime());
pstm.setString(2, Integer.toString(post.getPublisher().getID()));
```

isn't working either.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Post_Comment (
  Comment_ID INTEGER(7) NOT NULL,
  Post_date_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Post_User INTEGER(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(Comment_ID, Post_date_time, Post_User),
  CONSTRAINT Post_Comment_Post
    FOREIGN KEY (Post_User, Post_date_time)
    REFERENCES Post (User, date_time)
    ON DELETE   CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT Post_Comment_Comment
    FOREIGN KEY (Comment_ID)
    REFERENCES Commentary (ID)
    ON DELETE   CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
;
```

Please help.

Comment: That's what the right way to use PreparedStatement

Comment: Remove the ";" at the end of your query and retry. Also show table definition of post_comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). You're not supposed to `replace()` the fields using the String functions.

You're supposed to call the ["set" methods of the PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

---

EDIT:

No, take a look at the available methods. And what types the database columns expect. If you want a date, use `setDate()`, if you want an Integer, then use `setInt()`. Example:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM POST_COMMENT WHERE Post_date_time = ? AND Post_User = ?;";

PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstm.setDate(1, post.getDatetime());
pstm.setInt(2, post.getPublisher().getID());
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Also note that the query uses `?` for *both* placeholders, not `!`.

Comment: pstm.setString(1, post.getDatetime());
        pstm.setString(2, Integer.toString(post.getPublisher().getID())); Not working either.

Comment: @Nausikaa Are the database columns VARCHAR?

Comment: 2- The columns are DATETIME and INTEGER

Comment: Sorry guys the problem was solved like one hour ago, the erro came from another loop with the original mistake, thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM POST_COMMENT WHERE Post_date_time= ? AND Post_User= ?;";

PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstm.setObject(1, post.getDatetime());
pstm.setObject(2, post.getPublisher().getID());
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry guys the problem was solved like one hour ago, the erro came from another loop with the original mistake, thanks and sorry.